# Can not configurate amCharts Stock Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amstock

I have a Stock Chart and I want to remove empty spaces between candles and to set axe to the right. So I added the following code:

```
var categoryAxesSettings = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
categoryAxesSettings.equalSpacing = true;
categoryAxesSettings.position = "right";
```

But it makes no effect!

Can't figure out where problem is :( Please help!

My code is exactly the same as this one - http://www.amcharts.com/demos/adding-removing-panel/ or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GppXgq

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

---

1) You seem to be creating a new instance of CategoryAxesSettings but not assigning it to the chart, so it's never used.

You need to assign to chart's `categoryAxesSettings` property:

```
var categoryAxesSettings = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
categoryAxesSettings.equalSpacing = true;
chart.categoryAxesSettings = categoryAxesSettings;
```

Or, if you need to modify just one parameter, it's easier to modify it directly, without creating separate object:

```
chart.categoryAxesSettings.equalSpacing = true;
```

---

2) Vertical axes are **value axes**, not category axes. So you need to use [`ValueAxesSettings`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ValueAxesSettings) to set their position.

```
chart.valueAxesSettings.position = "right";
```